# Transform a list into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new to python and have difficulties transforming some of the data types. I have a list of objects that have a lot of attributes and i want to create a better structure for them. The `old_list` is based 'Var' types that looks like this:

```
old_type.name='a_1_1'
old_type.value=3.0
```

The amount of indices and the type of the value may change :

```
[old_type('a_1_1',4),old_type('a_1_2',2),old_type('x_1',True)]
```

i would like to split the old name into letters and numbers and to create a `new_data_structure` to look ideally like this:

```
new_data_structure[0].letter = 'a'
new_data_structure[0].indices= [1,1]
new_data_structure[0].value = 4

new_data_structure[2].letter = 'x'
new_data_structure[2].indices= 1
new_data_structure[2].value  = True
```

and i spend quite some time, but i cant get it to work. i tried

```
 new_list= [[old_type[i].name.split('_'), \
                     old_type[i].vartype.value] for i in range(len(old_type))]
```

which creates wierdly deep lists (`new_list[0][0][0]` for 'a') and is also only with indices. i tried to make a dict with

```
new_dict = {'letter': old_type[i].name.split('_'),  'value',old_type[i].value for i in range(len(old_type))}
```

but here the `for` seems not to loop over the comma seperated keywords and putting a `for` between every comma didn't work either.

Then i tried to explicitly loop over the different keys

```
for i in range(len(old_type)):
    new_dict[i][letter] = old_type[i].name.split('_')
    new_dict[i][value] = old_type[i].value
```

but this overwrites each time and leaves only the last letter and value in new_dict. I feel like i am making this way harder than it should be.

So in total: Is there a way to transform attributes of a list of objects into a dict (list of dicts?) with keywords as said attributes?

Additional question: Isn't there something like `substr('_')` i python that qould only return the string part until the first '_'?

Thank you

Comment: Can you make a Class for this datatype, and see if you wrap everything you described here in that Class and it's attributes?

Comment: *Isn't there something like substr('_')* Yes, you can index & slice strings just like you can do with a list or other sequence object, e.g., `'abcdefg'[1:3]` will give you `"bc"`, etc.

Comment: it could be an own class, but then i wouldnt know how to loop over the list to fill each instances of the new class

Comment: Have the new class derive from the old class?

Comment: no, it has not. I just take some values from the old class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable using a simple list comprehension:

```
new_dictlist = [
    { 'letter': i.name.split('_')[0], 'value': i.value }
    for i in old_type
]
```

Since `split` returns a list, use `[0]` to access the first part.

Comment: OP might want separate `letter` and `indices` keywords for each dictionary.

Comment: i am glad to see that it takes someone else 2 minutes to figure out what i couldnt do in 3 hours :D. Thanks never guessed this is how you would need to set the brackets and that it is possible to take only a part of split

Comment: @wwii i do! i would take the `split` twice for that with [0] and [1:]

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the `indices` field; in that case `list(map(int, i.name.split('_')[1:]))` works as a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `namedtuple` and `split` and make a new structure like this,

```
>>> class OldType(object):
...   def __init__(self, val1, val2):
...     self.val1 = val1
...     self.val2 = val2
...                                                                                                                                                             
>>>                                                                                                                                       
>>> from collections import namedtuple                                                                                                                                                 
>>>                                                                                                                                                  
>>> cus_struct = namedtuple('CustomStruct', ['letter', 'indices', 'value'])
>>> x = [OldType('a_1_1',4), OldType('a_1_2',2), OldType('x_1',True)]                                               
>>> [y.val1.partition('_') for y in x]
[('a', '_', '1_1'), ('a', '_', '1_2'), ('x', '_', '1')]                                                                                              
>>> 
>>>                                                                                                                                                  
>>> new_ds = []
>>> for y in x:
...   letter, _, indices = y.val1.partition('_')
...   indices = [int(k) for k in indices.split('_')]
...   new_ds.append(cus_struct(letter, indices, y.val2))
... 
>>> new_ds[0].letter
'a'
>>> new_ds[0].indices
[1, 1]
>>> new_ds[0].value
4
>>>
>>> for item in new_ds:
...   print(item.letter, item.indices, item.value)
... 
('a', [1, 1], 4)
('a', [1, 2], 2)
('x', [1], True)
```

Comment: accepted the other because it is more precise for the question, but i like the dot indexing! i will look into `namedtuple`

Comment: @Finn Sure. It is basically just a class. The source of `collections` module is a good read :)

Comment: Namedtuple was the First thing I thought of when I saw the dot-attribute access.

Comment: @wwii Yep, i still remember the hettinger talk :)